# cv2.imshow() doesn't properly display image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I was trying to check on what data was actually being read in via cv2.imread() but whenever I do so I get a full grey screen. I should be getting a rainbow image instead.

```
def detect_pixels():
    txt_parts = {}
    path = r'C:\Users\Singh\Documents\jpgtotxt\rainbow.jpg'
    BRG = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.imshow('BRG', BRG)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `time.sleep(3)` with `cv2.waitKey(3000)`.

Answer (score 1):

add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def detect_pixels():
    txt_parts = {}
    path = r'C:\Users\Singh\Documents\jpgtotxt\rainbow.jpg'
    BRG = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.imshow('BRG', BRG)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.